# how to play two different songs on different earphones at the same time through Gstreamer?

Tags: audio, gstreamer

We have tried playing two songs at the same time using interleave plugin.

```
> gst-launch
    filesrc location=/home/test.mp3
        ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! "audio/x-raw-int,channels=2"
        ! alsasink 
    filesrc location=/home/song.mp3
        ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int,channels=2
        ! deinterleave name=d
    interleave name=i ! audioconvert  ! alsasink
    d.src0 ! queue ! audioconvert ! i.sink1
    d.src1 ! queue ! audioconvert ! i.sink0
```

i can hear two song together on both left and right earplugs.but i want test.mp3 to be played in right channel and song.mp3 to be played in  left channel.
If in above pipeline I change channels=1 instead of 2 it says

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
>   Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
>   And i can hear nothing.

can anyone suggest me the correct pipeline structure for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before interleaving two songs you need to convert them to mono. It's possible to do this with audioconvert. Just set channels to 1.

```
audioconvert ! "audio/x-raw-int,channels=1"
```

Then just `interleave` them into one stream:

```
$ gst-launch                                                      \
    interleave name=i ! alsasink                                  \
    filesrc location=07.\ No\ Woman\,\ No\ Cry.mp3                \
        ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! "audio/x-raw-int,channels=1" \
        ! i.sink1                                                 \
    filesrc location=11.\ Sun\ Is\ Shining.mp3                    \
        ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! "audio/x-raw-int,channels=1" \
        ! i.sink0
```

**Upd**: Oh, my! It's almost the same pipeline on the `interleave` page [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-interleave.html). Try to read some docs before asking next time. It's not that hard.

Comment: Thanx for your reply.I tried with the pipeline u mentioned with channels=1   >>gst-launch interleave name=i ! alsasink filesrc location=/home/Smith/Desktop/FORCE/song.mp3 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int,channels=1 ! i.sink0  filesrc location=/home/Smith/Desktop/FORCE/test.mp3 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int,channels=1 ! i.sink1
But i am getting error WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link audioconvert0 to i

Comment: Yeah, sorry. it must be `sink1` before `sink0`. See updated post.

Comment: Can u please suggest me that if i want only one song to play in either left or right earphone then will we use interleave or some other plugin?I tried audiotestsrc one with freq=500 and other with freq=0 and we could hear beep sound only in one.But i m not getting what to do for mp3 to be played only in one.

Comment: Just replace one of the `filesrc ... audioconvert` parts with `audiotestsrc wave=silence`

Comment: thanx it worked.if i put audiotestsrc freq=0 then too its working.Is it same as wave =silence or different?

Comment: @user1113274, actually it is not the same, just look at the source: [silence](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/gst/audiotestsrc/gstaudiotestsrc.c#n570) vs. [sine](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/gst/audiotestsrc/gstaudiotestsrc.c#n423)

Comment: Dear @Pragya, this is not how SO works. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and some notes about [commenting](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @maxtaldykin 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077052/how-to-modify-the-following-command-line   could you take a look at this question?