# how to modify the following command line?

Tags: linux, voip, gstreamer, rtp, voice

I have the following gstreamer Command-line :

```
gst-launch alsasrc ! mulawenc ! rtppcmupay ! udpsink host= 127.0.0.1 port=5555
```

It records **Mono Voice** and i can hear it ,if i listen on 5555 port ( echo IP was used). But i need to transmit Stereo .
I have also tried my Microphone for stereo-recording Capability using the following command:

```
arecord -vv -fdat voiceFile.wav
```

and it works.
Does anyone know how to specify **stereo** in the gstreamer command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `rtppcmupay` does not support stereo:

```
$ gst-inspect rtppcmupay
...
    Capabilities:
      audio/x-mulaw
               channels: 1
                   rate: 8000
....
```

You can try some other codec (e.g. vorbis):

```
$ gst-launch alsasrc \
  ! 'audio/x-raw-int,channels=2' \
  ! audioconvert \
  ! vorbisenc \
  ! rtpvorbispay \
  ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5555
```